# If I add a cosine to shah function, what would be final signal's period?

Tags: signal-processing, dirac-delta

For example:

Let's say signal $y = \cos(2\pi t) + \sum n \delta(t - n)$.

Is that signal periodic, and if yes, what is its period? I assume that shah function adds up spikes, doesn't it?

Comment: The shah function (Dirac comb) doesn't really add up spikes. The Dirac delta function $\delta(t)$ is really only meaningful in the context of integration since $\delta(t)$ is $0$ for real $t\ne 0$ and is undefined at $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

In distribution we are given

$$y(t)=\cos(2\pi t)+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n\delta(t-n)$$

Now, what is $y(t+m \times 1)$, for $m\in \mathbb{Z}$?